# restrict Formula field value to refresh on selection of certain picklist items

Tags: formula-field

I have a formula field that gets populated when the user changes the Status picklist field to Closed.
My formula field works fine when the user changes the Status picklist field to Approved. But  if the user changes the Status to anything other than Approved then what I see is the value on the formula field disappears. Basically the main use for these formula fields is to know who closed the case before.

I have read checking the Prior value using the PRIORVALUE fn is not supported on formula fields. Should this be done using a flow trigger? I would like to keep this as a formula field if possible.

Here is my formula -

```
If(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Closed"), LastModifiedBy.FirstName & " " & LastModifiedBy.LastName , '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas don't store data. They are calculated on the fly every time the record is queried. You need to use a normal field and then use an automation, such as a Flow or Apex Trigger, to store the value.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox